# C# FTPClient OpenRead returns No Such File or Directory

Tags: c#, ftp-client

I am maintaining a C# application that makes use of FTPClient (originally from CodePlex), where the application downloads files from a remote server using the OpenRead method with the FTPDataType set to binary.

There have been some problems where the application is throwing an exception

System.Net.FtpClient.FtpCommandException: /download/abc.jpeg: No such file or directory

Investigation of this has found that the file does exist, (I have checked this by using FileZilla) and breaking off the connection and then reconnecting, the file is then downloaded, but the problem then moves to a different file altogether.

What I am looking to understand here is whether this is a problem with the FtpClient API or the remote server failing to make the file visible for downloading. Has anyone experienced a similar problem, and if so were they able to fix it?

I am thinking about whether a further check before downloading would useful, such as the FtpClient.FileExist method, but if this is a problem with the API, then it may be a waste of time.

Comment: Please show the code you currently have.

Comment: There isn't much to show apart from this.client.OpenRead(remoteFileName, FtpDataType.Binary); that is the necessary line and that's where the error is coming from

Comment: All I am doing is stream a file in bytes and recreating it on my end. Open Read method returns a Stream